# Emoticons built in to the iPhone keyboard?

Tags: ios, messages

This Christmas, I got several text messages from my Mom on her new iPhone 3G. 
Several of them included emoticons in the body of the text like so:

[image]

I know she hasn't jailbroken her phone or installed any apps from the App Store.
I do know that she has iOS 5.

What are the step-by-step instructions to enabling emoticons on an iPhone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Click Settings > General > Keyboard
2. Click International Keyboards then select the Emoji keyboard.
3. Switch between the two keyboards using the little globe icon to the left of the spacebar.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS5 Apple has provided the facility of Emoji keyboard.

- First, you have to go to the Settings app.
- Then open General-> Keyboard -> International Keyboards.
- Then you need to press "Add New Keyboard".
- At the end from the list of International Keyboards press the Emoji.

⛽

Answer (score 2):

From [this 9to5mac article](http://9to5mac.com/2011/06/08/standard-emoji-keyboard-arrives-to-ios-5-heres-how-to-enable-it/):

> To enable the standard Emoji international keyboard, go to the Settings app, navigate to General > Keyboard > International Keyboards and tap Add New Keyboard… From the list of international keyboard layouts choose Emoji. From now on, whenever you want to add some flair to your messages, switch to the beautiful Emoji layout by holding the globe key on your virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I happily wrote a blog post on this a little while ago... http://www.projecttoomanycooks.co.uk/blog/?p=1351  :)  It's got screenshots and everything...  (I've put the text, without the screenshots, below)

We're going to enable an extra keyboard on your iphone, and show you how to use it to get the symbols out.
Step 1: Switch on the keyboard
Nagivate to Settings->General->International->Keyboards->Add New Keyboard  and choose 'Japanese, Ten Key'.   Once it's selected, your Keyboards page should look a little like this:

Step 2: How to access and ^_^ symbols
Now open up a typing screen (we're using SMS in this example). You'll notice a globe has appeared between the '123' button and the spacebar, this button switches between international keyboards.

Make sure that you are in the text window (rather than the number window shown in the screenshot, and press our new globe button.  You'll find yourself on a japansese page (press it again to go back).   Should look like the screenshot below

Of interest here is the '^_^' button on the bottom row. That gives you access to a *massive* range of smilies - it's not the main point of this tip, but it's pretty handy...  two photos below

Step 3: Actually putting the icons in

So now the final part - from the Japanses ten key keyboard, press the 'ABC' key twice. You should find yourself on a numbers page. Looks like this:

You're now going to press and hold the '1' key.  You'll see a star appear to the left: slide over and press it, if you want a star, you're done. But if you want more symbols, press the arrow at the end for more of a range.

There's lots more symbols around that area, feel free to have a play.  Have fun!

Comment: I'd just reproduce the relevant info as an answer and include the link at some point.  Links for answers are generally frowned upon.  On the plus side, answers with pictures are almost universally upvoted.

Comment: I've popped the text in, and left the link for the pictures - would put more but in a little bit of a rush - was very excited to see a problem I could actually help with...